# Difference between dates format in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a query which filters through a table for items with a specific insertion date. The date is of timestamp format.

When I used the following comparison in the query, it works fine:

```
created > DATEADD(DAY,-5, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

But when I parametrize the query as below:

```
created > :tomorrow
```

where tomorrow defined as below:

```
$tomorrow = new \DateTime( 'tomorrow' );
$tomorrow->setTime( 0, 0, 0 );
$tomorrow = $tomorrow->format( 'Y-m-d');
```

Then it doesn't work. Does it have anything to do with the format of the tomorrow date?

Comment: Well your first query is "if created is more than 5 days ago" but your other query is "if created is bigger than tomorrow". So your queries are *not* the same, not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @WillParky93 it's just an example, what I meant is that when I parametrize it, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This is not timestamp:

```
$tomorrow = $tomorrow->format( 'Y-m-d');
```

If you want to compare a timestamp field for "tomorrow" use:

```
strtotime('tomorrow')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, when I do $tomorrow = strtotime('tomorrow') it stops.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `$tomorrow = $tomorrow->format( 'Y-m-d');` you tranform the original date in variable `$tommorow` to string. If you parametrized the date, no further transformation should be needed.